# c++ makefile using gcc - generate source file list from a list of subfolders

Tags: c++, makefile

So I have some rules that work:

```
# Folders
SRCDIR = src
SUBFOLDERS = test test/test2
OBJDIR = obj

# Just for me so I can read my own makefile :o
_TARGET = $@
_DEPEND = $<

# Get sources from /src and /src/test/ and /src/test/test2/
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp ))
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/test/*.cpp ))
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/test/test2/*.cpp ))
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(patsubst src/%, %, $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))

# Main target 'make debug'
debug: debugging $(OBJECTS)
    @echo building: gcc $(OBJECTS) -o out.exe

# Compiling each file
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    g++ -c $(_DEPEND) -o $(_TARGET)

debugging:
    @echo $(SOURCES)
    @echo $(OBJECTS)
```

**Note:** I had to hand-copy this code so there may be some errors, but hopefully its clear what I am trying to do.

Lets say I want to add some more source file sub folders: `src/another, src/andanother`. Now I have to add more `SOURCES = ...` lines to do this. Is there a way to do this in a rule. I have been tinkering with it but I can't come up with rules that work yet. What I want is that I add a new folder to `SUBFOLDERS` list and my code picks up the .cpp files automatically.

**note** I don't want to use things like `$(shell find ... )` because windows find sucks and I want this to be as portable as possiblt windows/Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use make's foreach.
like:

`SOURCES = $(foreach dir,${SUBFOLDERS},$(wildcard ${dir}/*.cpp))`

more info:
https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Foreach-Function.html

Comment: Cool : ) that is exactly what I needed - I had even looked around that same online doc, but I missed that.