# c++ makefile - how do you deal with rules for mixed source file suffixes (e.g. .cpp and .cxx)

Tags: c++, makefile

My project has mixed source files (due to 3rd party code), so we have some .cpp and some .cxx file.

Following on from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555670/c-makefile-using-gcc-generate-source-file-list-from-a-list-of-subfolders?noredirect=1#comment86118749_49555670) I have the following makefile:

```
# Folders
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
SUBFOLDERS = test test/test2
OBJSUBFOLDERS = $(OBJDIR) $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(SUBFOLDERS))
SRCSUBFOLDERS = $(SRCDIR) $(addprefix $(SRCDIR)/, $(SUBFOLDERS))

# Just for me so I can read my own makefile :o
_TARGET = $@
_DEPEND = $<

# Get sources from /src and /src/test/ and /src/test/test2/
SOURCES = $(foreach dir, $(SRCSUBFOLDERS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp $(dir)/*.cxx))
# Source file without the /src at the start, then take the basename, then add .o, then add obj/ to the front
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(patsubst src/%, %, $(SOURCES)))))

# Main target 'make debug'
debug: debugging $(OBJECTS)
    @echo building: gcc $(OBJECTS) -o out.exe

# Compiling each file
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp         <---- ISSUE HERE
    g++ -c $(_DEPEND) -o $(_TARGET)

debugging:
    @echo $(SOURCES)
    @echo $(OBJECTS)
```

So I have generated a list of source files and object files. The objects are mixed .cpp and .cxx. So my rule `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp` only works for .cpp files. I tried to make it `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c*` but that did not work. How can I make this rule generic to handle either. Or is there a better way?

If I remove the `$(dir)/*.cxx` from `SOURCES =` then this all works but only for .cpp files.

**Update**

Here is the outputthat I get:

```
SOURCES: src/main.cpp src/test/test.cpp src/test/test2.cxx
OBJECTS: obj/main.o obj/test/test.o obj/test/test2.o

Error: No rule to make target 'obj/test/test2.o', needed by 'debug'
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it fail to pick up the .cxx files?

Comment: SImply add a second rule: a `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cxx` rule. Mission accomplished.

Comment: either rename all `.cxx` files to `.cpp` or build 3rd party deps to a separate library using separate `makefile` where you'll have rule for `.cxx` and then just link to that library in your project.

Comment: @Clearer sorry - I will add the error....

Comment: Do what @SamVarshavchik tells you. That should fix the problem.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah, easy!... thanks, I did not think to use two rules : )    please feel free to add this as an answer I'll mark it up

Comment: @igagis mmm... in some cases this would be viable, but these 3rd party files are generated by a tool... yes I could do a script, but really I want to handle the situation - but a decent suggestion thanks : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple rules for building a targer from different extensions.

For example, the default Makefile rules already include rules for building `.o` from either `.c` or `.cpp`. `make` simply searches for the first mathcing rule, using the suffixes [listed for the `.SUFFIXES` target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Suffix-Rules.html).

In your case you simply need two rules:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
    g++ -c $(_DEPEND) -o $(_TARGET)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cxx
    g++ -c $(_DEPEND) -o $(_TARGET)
```

Comment: Actually you raise another point - how to handle .c files, I guess its easiest to just add yet another rule. I don't quite understand if I can get .cpp and .c (as a known suffix) to work in one rule..?

Comment: @igagis but other then renaming the files, is there another way?

Comment: Also can mitigate the duplication by having a variable like this: `COMPILE = g++ -c $(_DEPEND) -o $(_TARGET)` and then just use `$(COMPILE)` for each rule - this way we only need to edit the compile line in one place

Comment: You'll find that the default makefile has duplicate rules for `.cpp.o` and `.C.o`, etc...  Some minor duplication is unavoidable.

Comment: @code_fodder -- you could go a step further and use `defines` and `evals` in the makefile (for longer lists of recipes), but either of those can quickly make the code unreadable.  It may be justified if you have really complicated and repetitive rules.   Another option might be to do `%.cpp: %.cxx;  ln -s $@ $^`, but that can cause other issues (cleaning, editors that pull in all .cpp files, etc).

Comment: @code_fodder as I said in comment to your original post, would be more correct to build your 3rd party dependency using separate `makefile` to a library. And from your project to link to that library, so you will not work with 3rd party sources directly in your project.