# Compiling both C and CPP source in a single makefile target

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile where I am working with both C source and CPP source. Below is a snippet of code from the makefile. Is there a way to combine the following two targets to compile both filetypes?

```
#definitions
OBJ_DIR := obj
DEP_DIR := dep

CXX := g++
DEBUG := -g -O0
OPT := -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wall -pthread
LFLAGS = $(DEBUG) $(OPT) $(INC)
CFLAGS = $(LFLAGS) -c

#auto-dependency generation (part 1)
DEP_FLAGS = -MT $@ -MMD -MP -MF $(DEP_DIR)/$*.Td
POSTCOMPILE = @mv -f $(DEP_DIR)/$*.Td $(DEP_DIR)/$*.d && touch $@

#compile object files from CPP source
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEP_DIR)/%.d
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(DEP_FLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

#compile object files from C source
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEP_DIR)/%.d
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(DEP_FLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

#auto-dependency generation (part 2)
$(DEP_DIR)/%.d: ;
.PRECIOUS: $(DEP_DIR)/%.d
include $(wildcard $(DEP_DIR)/*.d)
```

I have tried to use the wildcard function with a variety of different formatting using second expansion but to no avail.

I am using Make 4.2. The auto-dependency generation code was taken from http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `CFLAGS` contain C++-specific flags, and is typically use for C sources. `CXXFLAGS` is the standard C++ flag variable. You should typically also use `$(CC)` as the C compiler.

Comment: Using an explicity rule for building object files with `.c` or `.cpp` as the source is probably not a good idea. Make already has those builtin. Just specify the flags you need for both in `CFLAGS` (for `.c`-files) and `CXXFLAGS` (for `.cpp`-files). Most the variables you define, you *really* shouldn't. It makes it *impossible* to override those for the user -- only append to the `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` variables and don't define `CXX` at all.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Isn't `CFLAGS` C-specific instead of C++?

Comment: @KamiKaze I meant to say that `CFLAGS` in the shown `Makefile` contains C++-compiler specific flags. And as such should not be used for C sources (which is what `CFLAGS` is supposed to be for) in the current `Makefile`.

Comment: It's _possible_ (using `defines` and `evals`, etc), but the end result is messier than having two rules.   This was discussed a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49557377/8710344) (read the comments).

Answer (score 3):

Using the right variables as well as the [define](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canned-Recipes.html#Canned-Recipes), [call](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html#Call-Function) and [eval](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) features, the following is possible:

```make
EXT := c cpp

define rule =
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(1)
    $$(COMPILE.$(1)) $$< -o $$@
endef

$(foreach ext, $(EXT), $(eval $(call rule,$(ext)))) # NO SPACE before $(ext)!!!
```

*make* has implicit variables and rules, especially many `COMPILE.*` rules (you can see them all by issuing the shell command `make -p | grep 'COMPILE.* ='`):

```
COMPILE.c   = $(CC)  $(CFLAGS)   $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
COMPILE.cpp = $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
```

`CPPFLAGS` is used for preprocessor flags (`cpp` is the preprocessor executable in the GNU GCC toolchain). `TARGET_ARCH` is empty on most platforms by default.

---

Here is a full yet minimalist working Makefile with better auto-dependency generation (note that putting the `.d` files in a folder separate from the `.o` pointlessly complicates the makefile):

```
TARGET  := executable
EXT     := c cpp

SRC_DIR := .
OBJ_DIR := obj
DEP_DIR := dep

CPPFLAGS  = -MMD -MP -MF $(@:$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o=$(DEP_DIR)/%.d)
CFLAGS   := -Wall -Wextra -pthread
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11 $(CFLAGS)
LDFLAGS  := -pthread

SOURCE := $(foreach ext, $(EXT), $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)/*.$(ext)))
OBJECT := $(SOURCE:$(SRC_DIR)/%=$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o)
DEPEND := $(OBJECT:$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o=$(DEP_DIR)/%.d)

define rule =
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.$(1).o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.$(1) | $(OBJ_DIR) $(DEP_DIR)
    $$(COMPILE.$(1)) $$< -o $$@
endef

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECT)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(foreach ext, $(EXT), $(eval $(call rule,$(ext))))

$(OBJ_DIR) $(DEP_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

-include $(DEPEND)

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(TARGET) $(OBJ_DIR) $(DEP_DIR)
```

Also note that I chose to add the original source file extension (`c` or `cpp`) to the object file name (`.c.o` or `.cpp.o`) to tackle the case where we could encounter source files with different extension but with the same name.

Comment: There is definitely a lot of useful knowledge in this answer, thanks!